# url rewriting script not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In a nutshell the script im using is not working

the script

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profiles.php?key=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profiles.php?key=$1
```

the original url :
`http://localhost/profiles?profile_key=yasin%20allana`

the desired url:`http://localhost/profiles/yasin%20allana`

the error:The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

how do i correct the errors

note:the server is v 1.8.3 xampp

---

the complete htaccess script

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|txt|css|js|php|pl)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# BEGIN Expires
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
</ifModule>
# END Expires

#override the limit on upload in php
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in `/profiles/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /profiles/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ profiles.php?key=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: if you're getting `internal error` check Apache error.log most likely `mod_rewrite` isn't enabled.

Comment: `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` is enabled

Comment: check Apache error.log and see what error is showing up

Comment: `[Tue Mar 25 23:23:23.679176 2014] [core:error] [pid 5484:tid 1676] [client ::1:53990] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://localhost/home`

Comment: That shouldn't happen due to 2 `RewriteCond` I have. Anyway try updated code. Also are there any existing rules?

Comment: That is the problem then, paste those rules in your question.